# How to convert internet address 6 to internet address 4?

Tags: ipv6, tcp, ipv4

l'm tackling tcp/ip protocol and l'm looking for translating ipv6 to ipv4.

*l have an ipv6 adress  **fe80::1acf:5eff:fe47:8753/64**

l want to get the ipv4 corresponding, any suggestions ?*

Comment: What makes you think there's a static 1-to-1 conversion from v6 to v4?  This is possible only for special [IPV4-Embedded](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6IPv4AddressEmbedding-2.htm) addresses, not link-local (fe80::/10)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786632/how-can-i-convert-ipv6-address-to-ipv4-address

Comment: we can do it  look at : http://www.rfc-base.org/rfc-2373.html

Comment: what makes the given ipv6 fe80::1acf:5eff:fe47:8753/64 doesn't allow a corresponding ipv4 ?

Comment: You are confused. There are IPv6 addresses which can be mapped to an IPv4 address, but they have a special format and are not allowed to be routed on the public Internet. The IPv6 address you have is a link-local address which can't be routed at all. IPv6 and IPv4 are different protocols which are not directly compatible.

Answer (score 3):

IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols and the addresses are not compatible or convertible. There are some special cases that map an IPv4 address to an IPv6 address (usually used inside software stacks to be able to use IPv6 software to handle IPv4 connections). There is no way to map normal IPv6 addresses to IPv4 or vice versa.