# Getting Correct vs Wrong IPV4 Address in NodeJS running under AWS Lightsail [IP6to4]

Tags: node.js, ipv6, ipv4, amazon-lightsail

We are running under a BitNami instance on AWS Lightsail.

Current NodeJS looks like this:

```
function getClientIPv4(req) {
  let ipAddress;
  const forwardedFor = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
  if (forwardedFor) {
    ipAddress = forwardedFor.split(',')[0];
  } else {
    ipAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;
  }

  console.log(req.headers['x-forwarded-for'], "x-forwarded");
  console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress, "remoteAddress");

  if(net.isIPv6(ipAddress)) {
    ipAddress = IP6to4(ipAddress);
  }

  return ipAddress;
}
```

The developer added some debug to console:
[image]

My IP Address V6 is 2603:8080:c940:120:5983:c3e9:aed3:c91d
which ***should convert to 72.181.25.179*** (which is in Texas).

I think his IP Address is converting correctly (he is in Poland I think).

But the above routine converts it to 174.211.201.29, which is in New York.

Some online web page converters, also make the same mistake:

[image]

This conversion routine is being used now, but it gives wrong result as well as other libraries that have been attempted:

```
function IP6to4(ip6) {
  function parseIp6(ip6str) {
    const str = ip6str.toString();

    // Initialize
    const ar = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) ar[i] = 0;

    // Check for trivial IPs
    if (str == '::') return ar;

    // Parse
    const sar = str.split(':');
    let slen = sar.length;
    if (slen > 8) slen = 8;
    let j = 0;
    i = 0
    for (i = 0; i < slen; i++) {
      // This is a "::", switch to end-run mode
      if (i && sar[i] == '') {
        j = 9 - slen + i;
        continue;
      }
      ar[j] = parseInt(`0x0${sar[i]}`);
      j++;
    }

    return ar;
  }
```

Comment: Another website says your IPv6 address is not IPv4 mapped so it cannot be converted: https://dnschecker.org/ipv6-to-ipv4.php Most IPv6 addresses are not convertible to IPv4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786632/how-can-i-convert-ipv6-address-to-ipv4-address IPv6 addresses are not just a different representation of IPv4 addresses, they are their own completely separate thing. That conversion algorithm you posted looks extremely naive to me, and I'm not even sure what you would stand to gain by doing this conversion, other than data loss.

Comment: @MarkB - so can NodeJS get an IP address from AWS Lightsail.  Or is it Apache or Bitnami or the AWS infrastructure that sets the fact that it uses IPV6?

Comment: IPv6 addresses are 128 bits, while IPv4 addresses are 32 bits. That means there are 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336 IPv6 addresses for every one IPv4 address. How would you propose to do a conversion from IPv6 to IPv4. They are two separate, incompatible protocols.

Comment: Your device (laptop, cellphone, whatever) has an IP address of `2603:8080:c940:120:5983:c3e9:aed3:c91d`. That's the device's IP address. It is IPv6 because of the network the device is on. None of this is because your server is on AWS, Lightsail, NodeJS whatever. This is all due to the client's (user's) network connection to the Internet. When you got the IPv6 address you got the IP address. That is the client's IP address. When you say you want to get an IP address from that, it doesn't make much sense, because you already did. Converting that to IPv4 just destroys the actual IP address.

Comment: @MarkB I have an IP Address database we purchased that IPV4 addresses in it. 
This is a different company, but talks about converting IPV6 to IPV4. 
Wondering if I can add new columns and index in my lookup DB, or do I have to find a provider that has IPV6 to locations?

Comment: @MarkB Regarding: "This is all due to the client's (user's) network connection to the Internet."  How does a website like "What is My IP Address" show both, and NodeJS cannot?

Comment: Also - windows IPCONFIG command shows: 
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::132f:ba8:74b9:6ae3%23
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.96.1
and  Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2603:8080:c940:120:5983:c3e9:aed3:c91d
So I don't just have one IP Address.  What determines which one is passed to a server from the browser?

Comment: By default, IPv6 is used if possible, and IPv4 is used when IPv6 is not possible. Websites like "what's my IP" set up two seperate connections, one to an IPv6 server and one to an IPv4 server. You cannot convert IPv6 to IPv4, if you want to find the location for an IP address you need mappings for IPv4-to-location and IPv6-to-location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, you **cannot convert** addresses from IPv6 to IPv4. They're two completely independent networks that merely go over the same wires but do not interact in any way – a network operator (an ISP) could have entirely different systems for IPv4 addressing and IPv6 addressing, and *only that operator* could possibly know the relationship between the two. They're not convertable.

(For that matter, there are many servers and devices that have IPv6 but *no* IPv4 address at all. There are even whole *networks* that don't have IPv4, only IPv6.)

Tools that claim to "convert" IPv6 to IPv4 only work correctly with a few *very specific* cases (exceptions to the above) that weren't generally applicable even in the 2000s when they were mildly common, and even less so today.

For example, if the IPv6 address is a '6to4' or 'Teredo' or 'ISATAP' address, it can be converted because it was indeed based on an IPv4 address originally – those are all "transition" mechanisms that were meant for providing IPv6 connectivity across an otherwise IPv4-only network, so embedding the IPv4 address was a necessity. But when it comes to *native* IPv6 connectivity, that's no longer the case – native IPv6 does not rely on IPv4 in any way.

The tool that you have in your screenshot overgeneralizes and tries to apply the ISATAP conversion rule ("take the last 4 bytes") to every address even if it doesn't have the hallmark of being an ISATAP address. So, of course, it gets completely nonsensical results.

> I have an IP Address database we purchased that IPV4 addresses in it. This is a different company, but talks about converting IPV6 to IPV4. Wondering if I can add new columns and index in my lookup DB, or do I have to find a provider that has IPV6 to locations?

You have to find a provider that has 'IPv6 to locations'.

> windows IPCONFIG command shows:
>
> ```
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
> Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::132f:ba8:74b9:6ae3%23
> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.96.1
> Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2603:8080:c940:120:5983:c3e9:aed3:c91d
> ```
>
> So I don't just have one IP Address. What determines which one is passed to a server from the browser?

The browser always starts by doing a DNS lookup for the domain name, to determine what kind of addresses the *server* has, again because the networks are independent and it has to use the same kind of address as the server. So if the domain has IPv6 addresses ('AAAA' DNS records) then the browser will try IPv6; and if the domain has IPv4 ('A' records) then the browser will try IPv4. When both are available, browsers usually try both simultaneously while other programs try one after another.

While the browser decides which network to use, it's usually the client OS that selects the specific address to connect from. If IPv6 is being attempted, then the OS will choose the address based on several rules, one of which is "scope" – which rules out the 'link-local' address because it cannot be used for anything beyond the direct connection – and another is "longest prefix match" which matches global Internet addresses (`2xxx:`) with another global address, or private LAN addresses (`fdXX:`) with another private address. In addition, temporary "privacy" addresses are prioritized over permanent addresses.

> How does a website like "What is My IP Address" show both, and NodeJS cannot?

The website tricks the browser into making multiple connections, one of each kind.

The initial request to the server is always just one type, either IPv4 or IPv6. In order to get the other type, the website needs to use client-side XHR or iframes to force the browser to connect through an "IPv4-only" subdomain or through an "IPv6-only" subdomain.

For example, if you visit `whatismyip.com`, it doesn't show any address at first – it just shows "Detecting…" for both – and you'll see these two XHR requests being made:

[image]

The first domain is IPv4-only, forcing the browser to make an IPv4 connection. (The second ought to be IPv6-only but it's apparently enough that it merely has IPv6 as the browser will try that first anyway.)

All such websites work the same way, e.g. another example:

[image]

The important part here is that the server request handler always sees **only one or the other** at any time. It's only the client-side webapp that is able to combine both.

Comment: Great answer!  In my IP Database, can I convert IPV4 to IPV6 and add two more columns?  Our main goal is to find the city/country of the client.

Comment: Also no. What I wrote applies in both directions – there really is no relationship in one direction or the other; you can't convert to IPv6 any more than you can convert to IPv4. You need to get a separate database.